# Spring boot micro service project structure and GIT braching

Tags: git, spring-boot, branch

Working on a spring boot based micro services project. Trying to come up with the maven project structure while GIT as repository. Multi-module project is the way to control dependencies and align services under one parent project. What happens when services need to be released separately with changes and need to do branching in GIT? The whole parent project is branched for the sake of one individual service? Is there a pattern where each micro service is a individual project in GIT but the dependencies across the micro services are controlled by POM import which defines the versions (though overriding the version is possible)? So, when there is a need to release one service alone, the branching is done for that service and other services are not forked?

Any patterns on the best practice to control library versions across multiple services that caters for GIT branching?

Answer (score 0):

Microservices, aka microservice architecture, is an architectural style that structures an application as a collection of small autonomous services, modeled around a business domain. In a Microservice Architecture, each service is self-contained and implements a single business capability.

The principles used to design Microservices are as follows:

- Independent & Autonomous Services
- Scalability
- Decentralization
- Resilient Services
- Real-Time Load Balancing
- Availability
- Continuous delivery through DevOps Integration
- Seamless API Integration and Continuous Monitoring
- Isolation from Failures
- Auto -Provisioning

In summary, I don't think your hierarchy on the project is compliant with the Microservices pattern, it's more close to a monolith application where you have hard coupling between the project